# Data types that can be encoded into the QR code

Tags: php, html, css, qr-code

I have a qr code which goes like this---

```
       <?php
include('phpqrcode/qrlib.php');
    $codeText="";
    $codeText .="Co-ordinates: "."x:10;y:50\n";
    $codeText .="Dynamic URL: "."https://www.google.com \n";  


    QRcode::png($codeText,'xyz.png',QR_ECLEVEL_H,4,10);
    echo '<img src="/xyz.png" height="500" with="500" />';  
        ?>
```

There is a question that can we make this **URL dynamic (i.e. redirecting to the respecting website automatically after a few seconds)? If yes then how can we achieve this?**
Though I haven't tested the output image in my smartphone by scanning.

**But more importantly my *MAIN question* is can we only encode simple `text` data in qrcode?** Or we can also do something like this:

```
        $codeText='<div class="mainCont">';
        $codeText .='<div class="cont">Co-ordinates: x:10;y:50\n</div>';
        $codeText .='<div class="cont">Dynamic URL: https://www.google.com \n</div>'; 
        $codeText="</div>";
```

Its a `html` and `css` encoded in qrcode ***I don't know whether this is possible or not!*** Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Anything can be encoded into a QRCode. It has a binary mode. Whether or not your library is capable of this or not is the question.

Comment: What would you expect the encoded HTML to do when scanned? If you want it to be shown in a browser, that probably won't happen in most barcode scanning apps. I would suggest putting the html/css on a webserver and putting a link in the qr-code.

Comment: OK @BobBrinks i got u . but i want users when scanned the qr code will be able to see the data. Question 1) can the data be styled? 2) can we let user see the data and redirect to the link after a few seconds?

Comment: Basically no, what is done with the encoded information is up to the App that does the scanning. Most apps will just show it plane text or follow an url directly/make it clickable.